# Why does linebreak mess up my CSS in one case but not another? (see fiddles)

Tags: html, css, character-encoding, char

[image]

The only difference between [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rwhal06/t4910tr4/1) and [this other version of the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rwhal06/t4910tr4/5/) is that the 2nd one has `</label><label for="address_zip" class="zip">` *without* a line break after the closing `</label>` tag.

[image]

```
<label for="address_state" class="state">
    <span>State</span><input name="address_state" type="text" placeholder="CA" required="" class="field is-empty">
</label><label for="address_zip" class="zip">
    <span>ZIP</span><input name="address_zip" type="text" placeholder="94107" required="" class="field is-empty">
</label>
```

I've experienced similar weirdness before. Line breaks are tricky.

So, I figured "I'll live with the fact that the HTML won't have a new line after the closing label tag, even though that looks sloppy."

**However, then I noticed that a [nearly identical webpage](https://jsfiddle.net/rwhal06/t4910tr4/3/) I'd coded (with just different CSS) seems to be immune from this line break problem.**

[image]

**Why?**

Comment: Using `flex-basis` instead of `width` for `#payment-form fieldset label.zip` and `#payment-form fieldset label.state` `style` solves it on my Chrome. I don't know if that's any help.

Answer (score 0):

Your form is basically one long line, since there are no block sections such as `div`. You added a `display: flex` to each label, but not to `fieldset`, so that each label is on its own row.

When you add a break line between your labels, that break line is added to the HTML view as a space, which makes it too long to fit into one row.

Here is how the code should look like:

```
<div>
  <label for="cardholder-name"> Name </label
  <input name="cardholder-name" type="text" placeholder="Jenny Rosen" class="question field is-empty personHead">
</div>
```

You might have to redo some css to align it properly, but this is the proper format.

Comment: While your answer is largely correct, your statement "An input should not be inside a label" is not. Here's an [example from the HTML5 spec of an input inside a label](https://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#example-fd964515)

Comment: Thanks! Learned something. Though stylistically it's more work because you have to include a span to customize the text.

Comment: My code comes from the official Stripe example, so I'd have been surprised if wrapping an `input` with a `label` weren't valid (or at least very widely supported): https://stripe-payments-demo.appspot.com